# Send two strings from java code to php script

Tags: java, php, android

I have to send two strings from java android code to php script.

I just want from java to send name1, and name2, and to read this names in php scripts.

How to do this?

Comment: You would need to provide more details about what you are trying to do. From the Android tag, I guess you are using Java from the Android platform and need to communicate with PHP on the server side. If this is the case, using an HTTP request is the most natural thing to do.

Comment: Where is your PHP script? Behind a web server? HTTP client is the way to go then. If you just "have a PHP script" that you'd like to add to your app, you'd better port it to Java and make it part of your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up your php script to be served by a web server you can have a java http client call the php script and pass the strings as request parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Short questions get short answers

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html